# improve performance of group by clause with SUM aggregation function

Tags: sql, performance, oracle10g

I have a query that groups results in the order of 300,000 rows.

What I've tried is to create an index with the group by columns. When I run the query without the SUM function, the query seems to run pretty fast, but when I add a column with SUM, then the response time increases a lot. For example  no SUM query response in less than 1s (paginated), SUM query response in 20s.

Supposing there's a index on a,b,c,d,e columns and there are 300,000 records in TableA :

**response in less than 1s (in SQL developer, which shows first 50 rows):**

```
SELECT a,b,c,d
FROM tableA
GROUP BY
a,b,c,d
```

**response in 18s (in SQL developer, which shows first 50 rows):**

```
SELECT a,b,c,d,SUM(e)
FROM tableA
GROUP BY
a,b,c,d
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How long does it take with a `count(*)` instead of `sum(e)`?

Comment: Two comments:  First, edit the question and describe what "paginated" means.  That might have an effect on performance.  Second, show the index creation code for the index with all the columns.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks, I've edited my question regarding pagination, about the index, it is a compound index , for example create index on TableA(a,b,c,d,e);

Comment: Can you add the explain plan for both queries?  For example, run a query with `explain plan for SELECT ...`, then run `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);`.  Also, are the columns A,B,C,D, and E `NOT NULL`?  That can affect if the index is usable here.

Answer (score 1):

Your index makes accessing those column values trivial, but when you add in  `SUM(e)` each row must be scanned to create the aggregate.

A `COUNT(*)` in place of the `SUM()` would run quickly because the index contains all the relevant information.

Including fields to be aggregated in an index usually offers a negligible performance difference unless the table is particularly wide.  It may actually perform better to remove `e` from the index.

Creating a [materialized view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/basicmv.htm) will improve performance

Comment: . . The column `e` is already in the index according to the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks, missed that.

Comment: I did not up downvote but I gave upvote for the idea in materialized view.

Answer (score -3):

Give the output of the below queries.

```
explian plan for SELECT a,b,c,d,SUM(e)
FROM tableA
GROUP BY
a,b,c,d

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display());
```